# Why is "wiki page" the only option for a new page?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am using Sharepoint 2010, and trying to create a blank site for development. In Sharepoint Designer, when I create a new page, the only option for "content type" is "wiki page". is there a good reason for this? is there no "blank page" content type for blank sites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a "Basic Page" content type available.
You get a Wiki Page each time only because its your page library's only or default content type.

You can try to create a Document Library and allow content type management. Then, add the "Basic Page" into your newly created document library and set it as the default content type.
Then, when you create a new aspx page in SharePoint Designer, you will get a blank page.

Comment: i would just think that the ootb behaviour would be to provide a Basic Page page library...